# Divi theme: change overlay color from default blue to back

Tags: customization, buttons

On those pages I am unable to correct the the color of the button overlay.

As you can see, they are black now but when you hover over, the color is changed to un ugly blue.
I set the accent color to black in the Divi customization panel but I now want to correct this blue.

On those pages and on checkout, wherever you see a button, there's a mistake. I am unable to acces the CSS behind it, because this pages were generated with woocommerce when I installed the plugin.

Please help.

https://2h-2h.com/product/leather-gloves/
https://2h-2h.com/cart/

Answer (score 1):

Some CSS to change the attributes of the '`single_add_to_cart_button`' CSS class (which is used for the button; I found that while using Firebug to inspect the button element).

```
.single_add_to_cart_button:hover {color:#ccc; background-color:#444;}
```

Adjust the colors as desired. Put this in the 'additional CSS' of the theme customization.

Here's a place to figure out colors: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp .